Selenium python webdriver intermittently thowing error
We are seeing the below error intermittently when we run python test cases on Selenium
self = <selenium.webdriver.remote.errorhandler.ErrorHandler object at 0x7fb8457b1b70> 
response = {'status': 403, 'value': '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">\n...6 
The Squid Software Foundation and contributors\n *\n * Squid software is distributed under GPLv2+ license and inclu'}

Due the above error many test cases are skipped and failing.

We need code to solve your problem

Please read [ask], especially the part about [mcve] (MCVE). Take the code you are using, reduce it to an MCVE, and then post that code as text, properly indented and formatted. Post the full error message as text, properly formatted, and indicate on which line the error is occurring.

you seem to be hitting a proxy.... possibly localhost (which the driver uses) is redirected there?  You need to at least include your driver initialization code.

You can check at multiple levels:

status code 403 indicates that there is a 'Forbidden' response from the website. You can check whether the server is prohibiting access to Selenium driver.
Do you have proxy? is proxy blocking the access?


Hi @vikasHi vikas
we are no where requesting to this url. seems its default error response from webdriver
'status': 403, 'value': '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd"

we are above getting error when we execute response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
